# Postman/OpenApi 3.0.0 : import file with remote reference fails

Tags: rest, schema, postman, specifications, openapi

When I import a specification file (OpenApi 3.0.0) containing remote references to schemas and requestBodies description, Postman is not able to find schema for response from my spec file.
The ./components/schemas and ./components/requestBodies content are not parsed.

Is Postman able to read remote references ?

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. Import file
2. Generate Collection from OpenApi 3.0 schema

[spec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KtrG.png)

3. Collections : Get all users

[get users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQ69a.png)

4. Clic on example : "The users list has been succefully retrieved"
5. The expected response body is not recognized

[schema not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jc0y6.png)

The ./components/schemas/User.json is not found

```
{    
"value": "reference ./components/schemas/User.json not found in the api spec"
}
```

- App Type : Native App
- Postman v7.13.0
- OS: Ubuntu 19.04